# SQL Nested SELECT Statement Outputs XML Encodeded

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following in SQL (Microsoft) query

```
    SELECT      tblModule.module_id, tblModule.module_name, tblModule.module_desc, tblModule.Alias,
            case generic_flag 
                when '0' then 'On-Demand' 
                when '1' then 'Core' 
            end as application_type,
            case tblModule.notification_flag
                when '0' then 'No'
                when '1' then 'Yes'
            end as notification_enabled,
            case tblModule.deleted 
                when '0' then 'No'
                when '1' then 'Yes'
            end as application_deleted,
            tblModule.guid,
            case tblModule.enable_task_management
                when '0' then 'No'
                when '1' then 'Yes'
            end as task_management_enabled,
            case tblModule.enable_direct_to_edit
                when '0' then 'No'
                when '1' then 'Yes'
            end as direct_to_edit_enabled,
            case tblModuleType.module_type_desc
                when 'questionnaire Module' then 'Questionnaire'
                when 'Input and Validation' then 'Application'
                else 'Sub-Form'
            end as application_class,
            tblModuleStatusType.status_name,
            tblLevel.level_name AS target_application,
            tblModule.create_date,
            tblModule.update_date,
            (SELECT tblNavMenuGroup.nav_menu_group_name as solution
            FROM    tblXNavMenuGroupsModules INNER JOIN
                    tblNavMenuGroup ON tblXNavMenuGroupsModules.nav_menu_group_id = tblNavMenuGroup.nav_menu_group_id
            WHERE  tblXNavMenuGroupsModules.module_id = tblModule.module_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) as solutions

FROM        tblModule INNER JOIN
            tblModuleType ON tblModule.module_type_id = tblModuleType.module_type_id INNER JOIN
            tblModuleStatusType ON tblModule.status_id = tblModuleStatusType.status_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            tblLevel ON tblModule.target_level_id = tblLevel.level_id
WHERE       (tblModule.module_type_id IN (2, 7))
ORDER BY    tblModule.module_name
```

When I execute the query outside of the management studio it escapes the XML like so

```
<solutions>&lt;solution&gt;Business Infrastructure&lt;/solution&gt;&lt;solution&gt;Risk and Impact Analysis&lt;/solution&gt;</solutions>
```

Is there anything I can do to get the results inside  as XML?

Comment: So this query works as expected when executed **in** SQL Server. What do you mean by executing the query somewhere else? Could it be the code in this other place that gives you issues?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson very possible.  I have a call into the vendor to see if they are doing the encoding when the job that runs the qurey.  I just wanted to see if I missed something in construction of the query; syntax wise.

Comment: It does not look like you have posted the entire query but from what I can see this should give you a resultset with one column `solutions` that contains the XML the query is building. The result you are showing is adding a second layer of XML where `solutions` is a node instead of a column in the resultset.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I've updated the question with the complete SQL query.

Comment: Nothing strange there. Something else is turning the entire resultset to XML.

Comment: Thanks...  At least it's not me :D

Comment: @MikaelEriksson would there be away in SQL I can trick it by actually enter '<' '>' as strings instead?

Comment: Perhaps you want the entire query result returned as XML? Try adding `for xml path(''), type` at the end of the main query and see what happens.

Comment: Another thing to try is to remove `, TYPE` from the sub-query. It might do a difference.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, removing the ,TYPE resulted the same.  Adding FOR XML Path(''), TYPE to the end put everything in one node and escape everything.

Comment: Ok, back to the consumer of the query to see what happens there.